# Corona SDK function that runs only after a specific collision?

Tags: function, coronasdk

In Corona SDK, is it possible to write a function that runs only when an object collides with another particular object, not just experiences a collision in general?

Comment: Yes. Put .id on the object and check for that id. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use [Collision Filter](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html) using this, you can control who collides with.